# Recommended way to work offline with TFS having specific constraints?

Tags: git, visual-studio, version-control, tfs

We sometimes face the issue that individual colleagues of our team need to work offline with TFS.
This may happen if they have to debug their code on the customer site where possibly no internet connection is available.

Is there any suggested way to work offline and to check-in the changes later when the internet connection is available (f. e. if they are back in the office)?

In our case the following conditions are given and can unfortunately not be changed:

- we have to use a "Server Workspace" and cannot switch to a "Local Workspace" in the TFS Collection Workspace Settings (usually we work in the office having an internet connection and we want to use the feature "GetLatest on CheckOut")
- we have to use the TFVC repository and cannot switch to Git in the team project

  - as far as I know, it is not possible to use and synchronize two different repositories (TFVC and Git) in one Team Project
  - if this would be possible, the group of people sometimes leaving the office could use Git and the remaining ones could use TFVC
- since we do not work with "Solutions" but only with version controlled files, the "Go Offline" option of the Solution Explorer is also not an option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't have it both ways. Centralized version control is designed from the ground up to require a connection to the server.

Either you use a distributed version control system (like Git) or you start using local workspaces, which provide some quality-of-life offline work features.

The people that need to work offline can have local workspaces, while everyone else continues to use server workspaces. They could even convert their server workspaces to local workspaces right before leaving the office, then turn them back into server workspaces when they return.

Comment: Hi Daniel! Thank your for your answer. Is it possible that some developers in the same collection can use server workspaces and others are using local workspaces? I thought it is defined on collection level what type of workspace must be used by all developers in that collection. Do you think it could also be a possible/recommended solution that developers who need to work offline could use a Git repository and when the are back to the office they could synchronize their changes to the TFVC repository (using the Git-TF command line tools)?

Comment: Thanks a lot for this answer! It is really possible that I can change my personal workspace from "Server" to "Local". Just tried it...

Answer (score 3):

Use [git-tfs](https://github.com/git-tfs/git-tfs) and all your developers will be happy to go fix bugs on the customer site ;-)

They will even gain a better local workflow!